Rescue from a missing partial
In Rails 7, how do you rescue from a missing partial?
In the past, I remember I did something like
<%= render "calculated_#{state}", item: item, rescue nil %>

This should prevent a missing template error when, for instance, state is old and the calculated_old partial doesn't exist.
But now I get a syntax error.

<%= render "calculated_#{state}", item: item rescue nil %>

As @Alex pointed out you have an extra comma. Please note this will not just rescue when the template is missing but will rescue any possible error that could occur in that partial as well which could hide any number of issues.

You should check partial existing somewhere before view, for example in controller
ALLOWED_STATES = [].freeze

before_action :check_partial_for_rendering

def check_partial_for_rendering
  return if state.in?(ALLOWED_STATES)

  # here you can return error, or raise error, or anything
end

Or if you need skip rendering missing partial
before_action :find_partial_for_rendering

def find_partial_for_rendering
  @partial = state.in?(ALLOWED_STATES) ? "calculated_#{state}" : nil
end

# and later

<% if @partial %>
  <%= render @partial, item: item %>
<% end %>


Hi there. Thanks for your reply. My goal here is not to make sure the partial for the expected state is called but to avoid having a few empty partials for the states that don't need to render anything.

then you probably need special service that 1) fetch list of partials, 2) compare list with available states

@Sig then conditionally render the partial. e.g. render("calculated_#{state}", item: item) unless ['old','none_existent'].include?(state) blindly rescuing every StandardError is not a good idea.
